# Processing: Move centerpoint of a random Starfield to the center

Tags: random, processing, center, translate

I'm working on a little space simulation with processing. In the game you can zoom in & out of the solar system. To gove that a neat paralax effect, I want to zoom into the randomly renerated starsky in the background. So far I have everything working, but the starsky is zooming into the top left corner. I know I have to translate the origin point of the stars to (width/2,height/2), but I can't figure out how I do that.

Here is the code:

```java
int starCount = 1200;
float[] xStar = new float[starCount];
float[] yStar = new float[starCount];
float starSpread;
float zoom;

void setup() {
  size(1600, 900);
  frameRate(30);
  calcStars();
  zoom = 1;
}   

void draw() {
  background(#000000);
   for(int i=0;i<starCount;i++){
     fill(#fff7e6);
     noStroke();
     ellipse(xStar[i]*starSpread,yStar[i]*starSpread,1,1);
   } 

  starSpread = 1+zoom*0.001; 
}


void calcStars(){
    for(int i=0;i<starCount;i++){
    xStar[i] = -random(0-width);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<starCount;i++){
    yStar[i] = -random(0-height);
    }
}

void mousePressed(){
   zoom = zoom - 1;
}
```

(Click mouse to "zoom" out! *<- I want the stars to move to the middle not to the upper left corner*)

So, I have 2 arrays giving me 1200 random coordinates in the window. "zoom" is a simple float that's controllable with a slider. This variable controlls the spread of all the content. It's mutiplied by 0.001 to make the effect on my stars just slightly.

Now can somebody help me making the zoom happen as I intend it to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This code doesn't compile for me- are you missing a few closing brackets?

Comment: oh sorry yeah, I had some problems with the browser implementation. this will work. But the slider is not in it due to the missing libary. (edited the post)

Comment: /edit clicking your mouse multiple times will "zoom" it out to see what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to do this, but the basic approach is this:

**Step 1**: Calculate how far apart from the center of the screen each star is.

**Step 2**: Scale that distance.

**Step 3**: Draw each star that scaled distance away from the center point.

```java
int starCount = 1200;
float[] xStar = new float[starCount];
float[] yStar = new float[starCount];
float zoom = 1;

void setup() {
  size(1600, 900);
  frameRate(30);
  calcStars();
}   

void draw() {
  background(#000000);
  for (int i=0; i<starCount; i++) {
    fill(#fff7e6);
    noStroke();

    float centerX = width/2.0;
    float centerY = height/2.0;

    float xDistFromCenterX = centerX - xStar[i];
    float yDistFromCenterY = centerY - yStar[i];

    float scaledXDistFromCenterX = zoom * xDistFromCenterX;
    float scaledYDistFromCenterY = zoom * yDistFromCenterY;

    ellipse(centerX + scaledXDistFromCenterX, centerY + scaledYDistFromCenterY , 1, 1);
  } 

}

void calcStars() {
  for (int i=0; i<starCount; i++) {
    xStar[i] = -random(0-width);
  }
  for (int i=0; i<starCount; i++) {
    yStar[i] = -random(0-height);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  zoom = zoom + .1;
}
```

This works, and I think it's pretty close to what you were going for, but you might also consider refactoring your code to use a `Star` object that keeps track of its own position. Whenever you want to zoom, just tell each `Star` object to move. You could also draw your starts to an image ahead of time, and then just scale that image. Like I said, there are a bunch of ways to do this.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the quick and perfect answer! That's what I need! I was goiung for the image as a emergency solution, but I want the thing to be responsive and clean ;)